# How to customize word definition in vim?

Tags: word-processing

Suppose that i am editing a line such as below(just a bash command),my cursor is locating at the `monitor`'s `m`:

1.How can quickly move cursor at the `alsa`'s `a`?

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i  alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor  music.mp3
```

2.How can quickly copy the string `alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor`?
A word is a string which begins with a `space` and end with a `space`.How can?
If i can define such string `alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor` as a word,
press `b` and `yiw` can do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iskeyword` setting controls which charters are part of a "word"; you can add the `.` and `-` to it (`isk` being the abbreviated form):

```
:setl isk+=- isk+=.
```

And then `b` will go back to the "word" as you want.

This affects many things though, including things like `expand('<cword>')` that may be used by plugin, syntax highlighting for some filetypes, commands like `*`, and many more. Personally I found setting `iskeyword` more trouble than it's worth in almost all cases, also because having commands behave different in different filetypes is confusing.

---

Instead, I would use `F<Space>` or `T<Space>` in your example, `F` ("find") will find a character backwards, moving to it, and `T` ("'till") will do the same, but puts the cursor one character before it. `f` and `t` do the same, but search forward. `T` is clearly the better choice here.

To copy that entire string, you can use `T<Space>yt<Space>`.

Comment: This is also a WORD, so `B` or `yiW` should do

Comment: I had completely forgotten about those commands @D.BenKnoble! That's indeed much better. I should use those commands more.